# Referenced files compiled to output on save, but ignored on rebuild

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with two projects - one class library and one ASP.NET MVC project. The class library project contains a Typescript file. The ASP.NET MVC project contains a Typescript file that references the file in the class library:

```
Solution
    ClassLibrary
        Scripts
            basefile.ts
    MVCProject
        Scripts
            projectfile.ts
```

`projectfile.ts` has a `///reference` declaration to `basefile.ts`.

In the MVCProject properties, under the **TypeScript Build** page, I have checked **Compile on save**, and set **Combine JavaScript output into file:** to `Scripts\projectfile.js`.

When I edit `projectfile.ts` and save, the output file is in the right place, with the emitted JavaScript from the referenced file (`basefile.ts`).

However, when I rebuild the solution, the JavaScript from the referenced file is not emitted into `projectfile.js`, only the Javascript from `projectfile.ts`. (Build alone doesn't seem to affect the file; the timestamp remains the same.)

I've tried including a `tsconfig.json` in the project, to no avail.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community and TypeScript 1.5.4

How can I resolve this?

---

**Update**

The same thing (referenced files emitted on save, ignored on rebuild) when both files are in the MVCProject project.